# Swapping addresses of pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

How can one swap pointer addresses within a function with a signature?

Let's say:

```
int weight, height;
void swap(int* a, int* b);
```

So after going out of this function the addresses of the actual parameters (`weight` and `height`) would be changed. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I don't get the question. What addresses do you want to swap?

Comment: You can swap the values of weight and height but not their adresses

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to swap the addresses that the pointers are pointing to, not just the values stored at that address, you'll need to pass the pointers by reference (or pointer to pointer).

```
#include <cassert>
void swap(int*& a, int*& b)
{
    int* c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    int* pa = &a;
    int* pb = &b;

    swap(pa, pb);

    assert(pa == &b);  //pa now stores the address of b
    assert(pb == &a);  //pb now stores the address of a
}
```

Or you can use the STL swap function and pass it the pointers.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::swap(pa, pb);
```

Your question doesn't seem very clear, though.

Comment: Thank you for all your valuable answers. I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear as I intended it to be. This answer (*&) solution is what I was looking for. Once again - thank you.

Comment: This is bad practice and missleading code. 1) Unnecessarily complicated. 2) Mixes Pointers and references (Bad practice). I would reject such code from every programmer handling it over to me.

Comment: I can't agree (but I'm still new to c++ so I may be wrong). 1) Why is it bad practice? Are we not using passing objects by references whole the time? And pointer is an object so has the right to be treated like one too.2) What is complicated about this I can't really tell.3) I don't see that as mixing pointers and referencess - I just see that as passing object through reference which is quite regular practice of mine.4)Bad Practice? Well in B.S's book The C++ Programming Language are examples of references to pointers and they not marked as bad practice so I think if B.S do it I can do it too

Comment: In general: 1) Its better to use pointers OR References. Mixing them typically opens door to confusions and bugs. 2) The code still could be replace by std::swap. 3) If you calls swap(int*& a, int*& b) with your parameters swap(&width, &height) the call will probably result in a compiler or runtime error. The whole thing is just nothing else than weird.

Comment: 1) It really depends on the circumstances. Naturally storing the dereferenced result of **new** to a reference will be confusing. But this is a different thing here. Passing things by reference is a natural thing to do (e.g makes it clear that NULL pointers are not welcome). 2) Yes, the idea was to show how to do it yourself. And guess what `std::swap` uses - correct, references. 3) Compiler error, which it should as it doesn't make sense. It would also result in a compiler error if you attempted that through a pointer-to-pointer. `swap(&(&a), &(&b));`

Comment: why wont the two variables height and weight will get swapped by using simple swap (int * weight, int * height). can you explain it? it is really confusing

Answer (score 9):

In C++ you would write

```
 void swap(int *a, int *b)
 {
    std::swap(*a, *b);
 }
```

or rather just use:

```
 std::swap(a, b);
```

Comment: But this doesn't solve the question, at least not as I read it. The addresses of the variables should change, not the values?

Comment: Your solution works, but it is not intuitive like MSalters example.

Comment: Its amazing that such a simple question can raise so many conflicts. Please don't shoot!

Answer (score 7):

**The new answer** (since the question has been reformulated)

is that addressed of variables are determined at compile time and can therefore not be swapped. Pointers to variables however can be swapped.

**Old answer:**
this was the answer when the question still implied swapping the values of 2 variables by means of a function:

function call:

```
 int width=10, height=20;
 swap(&width, &height)
```

implementation:

```
 void swap(int *a, int *b)
 {
      int temp;
      temp=*a;
      *a = *b;
      *b = temp;
 }
```

or...without using a temporary variable:  ;^)

```
 void swap(int *a, int *b)
 {
      *a ^= *b;
      *b ^= *a;
      *a ^= *b;
 }
```

do watch out that the last method breaks for the case: swap (&a, &a). Very sharply pointed out by user9876 in the comments.

Comment: Thats C, not C++ and - if i may comment it - the last approach is less then intuitive.

Comment: redsoft: He has tagged the question both c and c++

Comment: red: intuitive or not...it's fast, and the name of the function clearly describes what is going on. One doesn't always need to understand the algorithm to be able to use it.

Comment: If you haven't seen XOR used to swap two variables then you've not advanced past the first lesson of computer science 101.

Comment: pp: truth is that a lot of programmers today don't know jack about bit manipulation (apart from rudimentary if statements).

Comment: That XOR trick is nothing more than a bunch of wankers trying to be clever (and not really succeeding). You cannot say anything about its speed since it's not specified what it will compile into (any half-decent compiler will do it in registers anyway which will make the speed difference moot. and make the saving of a variable irrelevant). The greatest crime perpetrated on coders is cowboys writing hard-to-maintain software. Anyway, thanks for listening to my rant :-) Not voting anything up or down here since it's both irrelevant and a dupe many times over.

Comment: Not having a go at you there, @reiner, I saw your smiley, and your first implementation works fine in C++ despite @Stefan's misgivings.

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would use the XOR trick on modern processors.  It will be slower.  If the processor executes exactly what you wrote, then the XOR trick is 9 memory accesses but the simple method is only 4.  On modern CPUs, memory accesses are much slower than anything else.  If the compiler optimizes the XOR trick to store intermediate values in registers so there are only 4 memory accesses, then you still have 3 XOR operations that aren't needed in the simple solution.  Also, a really smart compiler could inline the simple solution and it may generate no code at all.

Comment: Also: swap(&a, &a) is a no-op with the simple solution, but sets a=0 if you use the XOR trick.

Comment: hahaha... But at least we had a fun discussion in the comments about it! I agree that optimizations on this level are typically insane (if you need this level of detail switch to inline assembly). The age old wisdom is valid here: one never knows, without measuring.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you might be a bit confused about terms.

An object usually has an address. That is the location in memory where the object is located. Some temporary objects don't have addresses, because they don't need to be stored. Such an exception is the temporary "4" object in the expression `(2+2)*3`

A pointer is an object that stores an address of another object. Hence, for every type, there is a matching pointer. `int` has `int*`, `std::string` has `std::string*`, etcetera.

Now, you write about "addresses of pointers". They exist. After all, I wrote that a pointer is an object, and thus it has its own address. And you can store that address in another pointer. For instance, you can store the address of and `int*` in an `int* *`. But do you really intended that? Or did you mean the "address **referenced** by a pointer"?

Now, you give height and weight as examples. The standard way to swap them in C++ is simply `std::swap(width, height)`. Note the `std::`, which is the prefix for C++ standard library functions. `std::swap` will swap almost everything. ints, floats, wives. (j/k).

You have another swap function, apparently. It accepts two pointers to integers, which means it wants the addresses of two integers. Those are easy to provide, in this case. `width` is an integer, and `&width` is its address. That can be stored in the pointer argument `int* a`. Similarly, you can store the address `&height` in argument `int*b`. Putting it together, you get the call `swap(&width, &height);`

How does this work? The `swap(int*a, int*b)` function has two pointers, holding the address of two integers in memory. So, what it can do is [1] set aside a copy of the first integer, [2] copy the second integer in the memory where the first integer was, and [3] copy the first integer back in the memory where the second integer was. In code:

```
 void swap(int *a, int *b)
 {
      int temp = *a; // 1
      *a = *b;       // 2
      *b = temp;     // 3
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change address of pointers then you have to pass pointers of those pointers as your parameters:

```
void swap(int **a, int **b); //as prototype
```

Those examples are just changes values of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution will be:

```
void swapPointers(int** first, int** second) {
    int* temp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
    return; 
}
```